# JSONデータを変数に入れたい

Tags: javascript, json

こんにちは。

**～やりたいこと～**
JSONデータを取得して変数"json"に入れたい。

**～データフォーマット～**　
（本当は25個のオブジェクトが入っていますが、長くなるので3つに省略します）

```
[{
            "id": "bitcoin",
            "symbol": "btc",
            "name": "Bitcoin",
            "image": "https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/1/large/bitcoin.png?1547033579",
            "current_price": 10715.03,
            "market_cap": 198320416170,
            "market_cap_rank": 1,
            "fully_diluted_valuation": 225169693287,
            "total_volume": 21305953480,
            "high_24h": 10984.72,
            "low_24h": 10704.38,
            "price_change_24h": -251.52325309,
            "price_change_percentage_24h": -2.29355,
            "market_cap_change_24h": -4380438062.130676,
            "market_cap_change_percentage_24h": -2.16104,
            "circulating_supply": 18495956.0,
            "total_supply": 21000000.0,
            "max_supply": 21000000.0,
            "ath": 19665.39,
            "ath_change_percentage": -45.44191,
            "ath_date": "2017-12-16T00:00:00.000Z",
            "atl": 67.81,
            "atl_change_percentage": 15722.47718,
            "atl_date": "2013-07-06T00:00:00.000Z",
            "roi": null,
            "last_updated": "2020-09-21T10:14:16.879Z"
        }, {
            "id": "ethereum",
            "symbol": "eth",
            "name": "Ethereum",
            "image": "https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/279/large/ethereum.png?1595348880",
            "current_price": 359.12,
            "market_cap": 40471151211,
            "market_cap_rank": 2,
            "fully_diluted_valuation": null,
            "total_volume": 10905063094,
            "high_24h": 381.06,
            "low_24h": 358.31,
            "price_change_24h": -20.86671684,
            "price_change_percentage_24h": -5.4915,
            "market_cap_change_24h": -2366520689.0932846,
            "market_cap_change_percentage_24h": -5.52439,
            "circulating_supply": 112692188.249,
            "total_supply": null,
            "max_supply": null,
            "ath": 1448.18,
            "ath_change_percentage": -75.198,
            "ath_date": "2018-01-13T00:00:00.000Z",
            "atl": 0.432979,
            "atl_change_percentage": 82855.06416,
            "atl_date": "2015-10-20T00:00:00.000Z",
            "roi": {
                "times": 43.793452701267505,
                "currency": "btc",
                "percentage": 4379.345270126751
            },
            "last_updated": "2020-09-21T10:13:09.402Z"
        }, {
            "id": "tether",
            "symbol": "usdt",
            "name": "Tether",
            "image": "https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/325/large/Tether-logo.png?1598003707",
            "current_price": 0.99949,
            "market_cap": 15192543383,
            "market_cap_rank": 3,
            "fully_diluted_valuation": null,
            "total_volume": 36094542207,
            "high_24h": 1.0,
            "low_24h": 0.997493,
            "price_change_24h": -0.00173808,
            "price_change_percentage_24h": -0.17359,
            "market_cap_change_24h": -14059318.47340584,
            "market_cap_change_percentage_24h": -0.09246,
            "circulating_supply": 15200298753.8702,
            "total_supply": 10166574840.0,
            "max_supply": null,
            "ath": 1.32,
            "ath_change_percentage": -24.40035,
            "ath_date": "2018-07-24T00:00:00.000Z",
            "atl": 0.572521,
            "atl_change_percentage": 74.71069,
            "atl_date": "2015-03-02T00:00:00.000Z",
            "roi": null,
            "last_updated": "2020-09-21T10:08:05.185Z"
        }]
```

**～問題点～**
下記のコードを書いたのですが、HTMLのページプレビューをしてもデータが表示されません。
（試しに、直接JSONデータをコード内に打ち込んでjson変数に入れてみたところ、きちんとテーブルが表示されましたので、JSONの読み込みコード部分に問題があるのかと思うのですが、どこがおかしいのかがわかりません。）

```
   <body>

    <!--テーブル位置-->
    <div id='maintable'></div>


    <script>
        // ここでjsonデータを読み込めるようにしたい。
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.open("GET", 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=25&page=1&sparkline=false', true);
            request.responseType = 'json';
            req.send();
            req.onload = function() {
                const json = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
            };
        });


        //jsonのデータを使って、必要な項目のみのオブジェクトを新たに作成
        var toplist = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
            toplist[i] = {};
            toplist[i]["RANK"] = json[i]["market_cap_rank"];
            toplist[i]["NAME"] = json[i]["name"];
            toplist[i]["PRICE"] = json[i]["current_price"];
            toplist[i]["CHANGE"] = json[i]["price_change_percentage_24h"];
            toplist[i]["MARKET CAP"] = json[i]["market_cap"];
        }

        // table要素を生成  
        var table = document.createElement('table');
        var tr = document.createElement('tr'); // ヘッダーを作成
        for (key in toplist[0]) {
            var th = document.createElement('th'); // th要素を生成
            th.textContent = key; // th要素内にテキストを追加
            tr.appendChild(th); // th要素をtr要素の子要素に追加
        }
        table.appendChild(tr); // tr要素をtable要素の子要素に追加

        // テーブル本体を作成
        for (var i = 0; i < toplist.length; i++) {　　
            var tr = document.createElement('tr'); // tr要素を生成
            for (key in toplist[0]) {　 // th・td部分のループ
                var td = document.createElement('td');
                / td要素を生成
                td.textContent = toplist[i][key]; // td要素内にテキストを追加
                tr.appendChild(td); // td要素をtr要素の子要素に追加
            }
            table.appendChild(tr); // tr要素をtable要素の子要素に追加
        }

        // 生成したtable要素を追加する
        document.getElementById('maintable').appendChild(table);
    </script>

</body>
```

おわかりの方教えていただければ幸いです。
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 変数"list"は、何の配列ですか？　元になるJSONデータは、どういう仕様で書かれているのですか？
　単純な一覧のようなJSONと、何重にもネストしているようなJSONでは、listに入るデータの構造が異なりますから、どんなJSONデータを使って、どのような値を変数"list"に入れたいのかを明らかにしてください。

　データの取得についての、うまくいっていないのですか？　どのようにうまくいっていないのかを説明しないと、回答が得られないと思いますよ。「苦戦してます」だけで回答は無理ですから。

Comment: 情報が足りず申し訳ありません。追記しました。

Comment: 回答にあたって知りたいのは **JSON データのフォーマット** なので、単にURLで指し示すのではなく質問文に直接データ (の一部) をフォーマットが分かるように貼り付けてもらった方がより親切かなと思います。

Comment: JSONデータの一部を追記し、より詳しく質問内容を記載しました。どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: `req.onload = function() { const json = JSON.parse(req.responseText); };`　この関数の外で変数"json"を使えません。（[これ](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Glossary/Scope)を参考にしてください。）テーブルを作るコードをこの関数の中に移せばいいと思います。

Comment: スコープは当然ですが，onloadがコールバックとして非同期に実行される，というのも大事ですね

Comment: 皆さんご回答・コメントありがとうございました。とても参考になり助かりました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

まず、`request.responseType = 'json';` requestは、`req`ですよね
responseTypeにjson を指定したので　responseで受け取ります。`json = req.response;`

詳しくは、[XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) を見てください。

**以下、スクリプト例です。**

```
const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=25&page=1&sparkline=false', true);
req.responseType = 'json';
req.send();
req.onload = function() {
    if( req.readyState == 4 ) {// データ受信完了.
            if( req.status == 200 || req.status == 304 ) {
                let json = req.response;
                console.log( json[0].market_cap_rank );
            }
    }
};
```

補足、
今回はrequest が定義されていないのでReferenceErrorで止まってしまいます。

responseTypeが指定されていない場合は、htmlもしくは　textで受け取ることになります。 request.responseTypeの行が無ければ `json = JSON.parse(req.responseText);`で受け取れるはずです。

処理を関数にまとめて（process(json); とか）req.onload内で関数を呼び出し処理するのが良いと思います。